# Почему может не работать пул объектов?

Tags: unity3d

```
// создает первый объект
public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform myObject;
    public int positionX = -4;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Instantiate (myObject, new Vector3 (positionX, -4, -0.5f), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}

// тут собственно заносится в пул и берется оттуда
public class ObjectPoolScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject myObject;

    public int poolAmount = 2;
    public List<GameObject> objPool;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        objPool = new List<GameObject> ();
        for (int i = 0; i < poolAmount; i++) {
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate (myObject);
            obj.SetActive (false);
            objPool.Add (obj);
        }
    }

    public void UsePooled(){
        for (int i = 0; i < objPool.Count; i++) {
            if (!objPool [i].activeInHierarchy) {
                objPool [i].transform.position = new Vector3 (0, 0, 0);
                objPool [i].SetActive (true);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

// а тут скрипт самого объекта
public class MyObjectScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject spawner;

    //возможность перетаскивать флаг мышью (или драг-и-дроп)
    public void OnMouseDrag () {
        Vector2 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector2 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y));
        gameObject.transform.position = p;
        gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center = new Vector3(
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center.x,
            gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center.y, 4);
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
        if (other.CompareTag ("TagSomeObject_1")) {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript> ().DoWork ();
            gameObject.SetActive (false);
            spawner.GetComponent<ObjectPoolScript>().UsePooled();
        }

        if (other.CompareTag ("TagSomeObject_2")) {
            other.gameObject.GetComponent<SomeScript_2> ().DoWork();
            gameObject.SetActive (false);
            spawner.GetComponent<ObjectPoolScript>().UsePooled();
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawner = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Spawner");
    }
}
```

Объект должен при любом контакте с объектами с тэгами вызывать функцию этого объекта (работает), затем становиться неактивным (работает ТОЛЬКО у первого объекта), заноситься в пул (только первый так делает) и потом из пула должен придти следующий объект (он не берется). То есть, первый объект, который появляется на сцене, при контакте делает все эти действия (вызывает функцию у другого объекта -> "уничтожается" и уходит в пул -> вызывает оттуда следующий объект), а вот все остальные объекты делают только это (вызывает функцию у другого объекта). При этом, если удалить вот этот код `spawner.GetComponent<ObjectPoolScript>().UsePooled();`, то все объекты при контакте выполняют еще и `gameObject.SetActive (false);`. В чем прикол, не могу понять. Пул объектов взял из официального урока по юнити, точно такой же уже есть для другого объекта (не могу использовать из-за параметров в функции, а все остальное то же самое) и работает он как часы. А тут что-то непонятное... Что я делаю не так?

Comment: skillsPool  - Что это? Что за пул такой из которого объекты не берутся и не возвращаются? Что делает UsePooled? Коментарии не там стоят....

Comment: @Valera Kvip Упс, не заметил. Все, вроде все поправил. Комментарии стоят к классам, а UsePooled смотрит, есть ли неактивный объект, и, если такой есть, берет его из пула

Comment: А почему первый объект берется не из пула? Много слов, но ничего не понятно. То что получилось разобрать: первый объект всегда стоит в начале пула, а следующие запрашиваются только когда первый объект стал не активен, следовательно -  он делает себя не активным, а потом в  UsePooled (где он стоит первым) делает себя активным - преступление раскрыто.

Comment: Не, он делает себя не активным, а активным становится следующий из пула. И вот он как раз не активным не становится(

Comment: Ну я уже сказал. Первый объект берется не из пула, а создается в первом скрипте. А следующий объект становится не активным, но он первый в пуле, поэтому сразу становится активный(смотри пред комментарий)

Comment: Если бы было так, то он появлялся на координатах 0, 0, 0, а он остается на той же координате, где выполняет DoWork(); В любом случае, дело не в том, что первый объект создается в другом скрипте. Удалил первое создание, вручную сделал объект активным. Оказалось, что не работает (не возвращается в пул) только первый объект, взятый из пула, остальные при вызове DoWork() возвращаются в пул и вынимают оттуда первый ("не рабочий") объект

Comment: Хотя все же похоже на то, что тут же активируется... Удалил из пула objPool [i].SetActive (true); и все объекты начали исчезать... Теперь бы понять, почему не исчезает только первый в очереди и как заставить его исчезнуть

Comment: Дело в том, что абсолютно аналогичный пул для других объектов, только с дополнительным параметром (влияет только на то, какой спрайт вешать на объект) работает как надо...

Comment: Итак, проблема не в классе с пулом - 100%. Я скопировал код из пула для другого класса не меняя вообще ничего, даже названия переменных. Для того объекта он работает, для этого ничего не поменялось - первый в очереди все так же не исчезает (хотя в том при таком же OnTriggerEnter() все норм)

Comment: Все, проблема в классе MyObjectScript. В классе с другим объектом у меня бокс коллайдер постоянно перемещается в Update() по оси Z, и почему-то благодаря этому в пул все заносится нормально (хз почему(( Видимо из-за того, что я не "держу" его там мышью, но почему тогда все кроме первого в очереди работают нормально?..). Убрал у того объекта весь код из Update() и то же самое начало происходить и с ним.